# How to calculate keys combination in c#

Tags: c#, key

I have to following code to `capture keys pressed:`

```
protected override bool ProcessCmdKey(ref Message msg, Keys keyData)
    {
        const int WM_KEYDOWN = 0x100;
        const int WM_SYSKEYDOWN = 0x104;

        if ((msg.Msg == WM_KEYDOWN) || (msg.Msg == WM_SYSKEYDOWN))
        {
            int x;
            switch (keyData)
            {
                case (Keys)131149: //case Keys.Control | Keys.M:
                    x = 1;
                    break;
                case Keys.Alt | Keys.Z:
                    x = 2;
                    break;
                case Keys.Shift | Keys.A:
                    x = 3;
                    break;
                case (Keys)196685: //Keys.Control | Keys.Shift | Keys.M:
                    x = 1;
                    break;
            }
        }

        return base.ProcessCmdKey(ref msg, keyData);
    }
```

You can see that the keys combination <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>M</kbd> == `196685.`

Is there a way for me to calculate other combination in my code?

For example: <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F</kbd> == ? etc...

Comment: Perhaps you mean `case Keys.Alt | Keys.F:`? (On another note, is there a specific reason you would attempt to find the numerical value that the combination evaluates to?)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Console.Write((int) (Keys.Alt | Keys.F))

Or more basic:

1000000000000000000 OR 1000110 = 1000000000001000110

Comment: Do You know how can i get it even in reverse from int to keys ?
For exemple if I have the number 196685 how can I know it means 
Keys.Control | Keys.Shift | Keys.M ?

Comment: 196685 AND Keys.Control = true or false that Control is set

Comment: Found it:
(char)196685
77 'M'
(Keys)(196685-(char)196685)
Shift | Control